# De-activate a maven profile from command line

Tags: java, maven, command-line-interface

I have a profile **activated by default** in my maven setting file **~/.m2/settings.xml**.

Is it possible to deactivate it from the command line by doing something like this:

```
mvn -P!profileActivatedByDefault
```

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Yes indeed, you have the right way.
From [maven profiles user guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html#Deactivating_a_profile)

> **Deactivating a profile**
>
> Starting with Maven 2.0.10, one or more profiles can be deactivated using the command line by prefixing their identifier with either the character '!' or '-' as shown below:
>
> `mvn groupId:artifactId:goal -P !profile-1,!profile-2`
>
> This can be used to deactivate profiles marked as activeByDefault or profiles that would otherwise be activated through their activation config.

As noted by @Calfater in the comments, the exclamation mark needs to be escaped in most shells (bash, zsh, and others on Linux and MacOS), though not on the windows command line.

The escape mechanisms are shell-dependant, but usually you can do :

```
mvn groupId:artifactId:goal -P \!profile-1
```

Or

```
mvn groupId:artifactId:goal -P '!profile-1'
```

Or, as [Shaun Morris suggested below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30129339/537554), use `-` instead of `!`, but **without whitespace** between `-P` and the profiles:

```
mvn groupId:artifactId:goal -P-profile-1,-profile2
```

Comment: This solution works but we need to escape the '!' character on Linux terminal:  `mvn groupId:artifactId:goal -P \!profile-name`

Comment: @Calfater : Indeed, this is worthy of editing the original post.

Comment: The escape character was killing me...in windows was working flawlessly Thanks.

Comment: @Calfater also had problem with exclamation mark using `zsh`. I just put `-P` between single quotes like this: `-P '!dev'`

Comment: @Derp : single quotes disable zsh / bash / ... interpolation. Thanks for the trick.

Answer (score 38):

On a Mac, I got the following error attempting to use '!'

```
mvn groupId:artifactId:goal -P!profile-1
-bash: !profile: event not found
```

Doing the following works with the '-':

```
mvn groupId:artifactId:goal -P-profile1
```

Alternatively you can do:

```
mvn groupId:artifactId:goal -P\!profile1
```

Comment: same on linux (macOS is ux-based operating system)

Comment: same on windows, the '-' char is required to de-activate default enabled profiles

Answer (score 6):

Starting with Maven 2.0.10, one or more profiles can be deactivated using the command line by prefixing their identifier with either the character '!' or '-' as shown below:

```
mvn groupId:artifactId:goal -P !profile-1,!profile-2
```

This can be used to deactivate profiles marked as activeByDefault or profiles that would otherwise be activated through their activation config.
[Refer Maven Doc](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

*Because `!` Exclamation mark is a special character for most of the command line tools, you might need to escape it [refer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270977/what-characters-are-required-to-be-escaped-in-command-line-arguments)*.

Comment: You're right that *activating* a profile through `-P` will ignore other profiles (e.g. `activeByDefault` or <activation>), but using only/exclusively the deactivation syntax (`!` prefix) will only deactivate those profiles, and not override the `activeByDefault` or `<activation>` declarations

Comment: The docs changed, now `-P` will add the profiles in addition to activeByDefault profiles: "This option takes an argument that is a comma-delimited list of profile-ids to use. When this option is specified, the profile(s) specified in the option argument will be activated in addition to any profiles which are activated by their activation configuration or the <activeProfiles> section in settings.xml"

Comment: Thanks for the up-to-date information. I do not know for how long this has changed.

@SparkOn : this changes the validity-scope of your answer, you might want to edit to to reflect this.