# Maven Plugin with a profile

Tags: maven, maven-profiles, aspectj-maven-plugin

I have a maven plugin with a profile that is active by default. I want to disable this profile and there doesn't seem to be an option to disable it using the plugin's configuration.  
I have tried [De-activate a maven profile from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201430/de-activate-a-maven-profile-from-command-line) and it didn't work. I am not sure if I placed the arguments in the right place. 
 
How can I deactivate the profile which is active by default?

Answer (score 0):

```
... -P !myProfileId
```

You should be able to disable it prefixing its identifier with either the character '!' or '-' as shown above.

Make sure you are using the correct profile id

Comment: This does not work. The profile I am trying to deactivate is in the plugin.